# Does there exist a perfect square in the form: $|x^2+52x|$, where $x\in \Bbb Z$?

Tags: absolute-value

Does there exist a perfect square in the form: $|x^2+52x|$, where $x\in \Bbb Z$?
$x<0,x\neq-52$

Comment: Não foi seu pai que traduziu

Comment: Seems the problem has been edited - the way it looks now it has all the context needed. With the extra conditions, $x<0$ and $x \ne -52$, there is still at least one (almost) trivial affirmative answer, $x = -26$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Let $x=-52$; then $(-52)^2 + 52 \times (-52) = 0$, which is square. Or let $x = 0$, to get $0^2 + 0 = 0$.

For a sensible answer, $144^2 + 52 \times 144 = 168^2$.